# Testing react with Enzyme: Spyon is not covering the code

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, spyon

I very new to react, I am trying to improve the code coverage. I used some of the link to use spyon to test my hooks but test passes but there is no coverage improvement. request your help.

Here us the sample code

```
import SimplePage from "../SimplePage/SimplePage";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { UrlContext } from "../../../../App";
export default function Degumming() {
  const apiRootUrl = useContext(UrlContext);
  return SimplePage({
    endpointUrl: apiRootUrl + "/api/simple/parameters/degumming/",
    tableTitle: "Degumming Table of ",
    columnsTitle: [
      ["stock Name", 1],
      ["Degumming", 1],
      ["", 1],
    ],
  });
}
```

Here is the sample test

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Degumming from './Degumming';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from '../../../../redux/Index';
describe('<Degumming />', () => {
    test("Test Simple Page render", () => {
        const apiRootURL =  "/api/simple/parameters/degumming/";
        jest.spyOn(React, 'useContext')
        .mockImplementation(() => apiRootURL);
        const wrapper = shallow(<Provider store={store}><Degumming /></Provider>);
        expect(wrapper.find('Generate Inputs')).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
});
```

What am I doing wrong :(

Comment: What's `SimplePage`? If the component is not related with redux, you don't need to use `Provider`.  And why `expect(wrapper.find('Generate Inputs')).toHaveBeenCalled();`? Does `wrapper.find('Generate Inputs')` returns a function?

Comment: It is an example code the SimplePage is page designed inside the application, not redux component